# Custom controls on ios (Examples inside entry)

Tags: ios, user-interface, custom-controls

I have a question that may be because I'm a newbie in ios development. I need to build a control very similar to this app: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/erudio-student-organizer-for/id515879580?mt=8

There are some native controls for get an similar interface to the first and second image?

If I can get a similar result with some native cotrol, what is or what are the most ideal?

If native controls can't do result I need, is the customization very difficult? Would it be enough with Quartz Core, or would need openGL- ES?

Comment: Each of those screens has several controls. Be more specific. Add a screenshot with just what you want to your question.

Comment: You can use table view for that UI.Apply different images to that cell according to your need.If you want to create custom control then it will be possible using the table view.

Answer (score 2):

The native control that will probably serve you best is the `UITableViewController` that manages a table view. To accomplish the appearance of the interface example that you have given requires significant customization of the table view and its cells. The two primary styles, grouped and plain, are illustrated in the first two screenshots. You may find routines in Quartz Core to be helpful. There isn't any need to use OpenGL ES as far as I can tell.